# if error then do something else - string split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['BERGEPAINT20FEB550PE', 'BANKNIFTY2020631300CE', 'BANKNIFTY2020631300PE'], columns=list('A'))
df['StrikePrice'] = df.A.str.split('(\d+)').apply(lambda x: x[3])
df['CallPut'] = df.A.str[-2:]
print(df.head())
```

I am looking to split the string in the above dataframe like below

```
BERGEPAINT20FEB550PE -> BERGEPAINT, 550, PE

BANKNIFTY2020631300CE -> BANKNIFTY, 31300, CE

BANKNIFTY2020631300PE -> BANKNIFTY, 31300, PE
```

but getting an error

Comment: you are splitting at any digit like this and try to access the fourth element by `x[3]`. but there arent 4 elements in `BANKNIFTY2020631300CE` because its split like `[BANKNIFTY, 2020631300, CE]`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
s = df['A'].str.split('(\d+)').apply(lambda x: [x[0], x[-2][-5:], x[-1]])
s.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).rename(columns={0: 'A', 1: 'StrikePrice', 2: 'CallPut'})

            A StrikePrice CallPut
0  BERGEPAINT         550      PE
1   BANKNIFTY       31300      CE
2   BANKNIFTY       31300      PE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with your given data, using a regex 'or' expression to split on.   Split on 5 digits or 2 digits:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['BERGEPAINT20FEB550PE', 'BANKNIFTY2020631300CE', 'BANKNIFTY2020631300PE'], columns=list('A'))
df['StrikePrice'] = df.A.str.split('(\d{5}|\d{2})').str[-2]
df['CallPut'] = df.A.str[-2:]
df['Name'] = df.A.str.split('(\d+)').str[0]
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
                       A StrikePrice CallPut        Name
0   BERGEPAINT20FEB550PE          55      PE  BERGEPAINT
1  BANKNIFTY2020631300CE       31300      CE   BANKNIFTY
2  BANKNIFTY2020631300PE       31300      PE   BANKNIFTY
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the part you don't want ("20FEB", "20206", "20206") all start by `20`and are composed of 5 characters, then you can use this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['BERGEPAINT20FEB550PE', 'BANKNIFTY2020631300CE', 'BANKNIFTY2020631300PE'], columns=list('A'))
df['Toto'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: x[:x.index("20")])
df['StrikePrice'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: x[x.index("20")+5:-2])
df['CallPut'] = df.A.str[-2:]
print(df)
```

Output :

```
                       A        Toto StrikePrice CallPut
0   BERGEPAINT20FEB550PE  BERGEPAINT         550      PE
1  BANKNIFTY2020631300CE   BANKNIFTY       31300      CE
2  BANKNIFTY2020631300PE   BANKNIFTY       31300      PE
```